# Embedding sqlite.c into Go code: ld complains about libdl while it should not

Tags: sqlite, go, cgo

I'm absolutely new to CGo. I don't want to use mattn's go-sqlite package and would like to build my own minimal interface to SQLite.

I'm trying to get compiled the simplest program on my linux machine with `go build`, and it always returns the same error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o: in function `unixDlError':
./sqlite3.c:42036: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o: in function `unixDlClose':
./sqlite3.c:42067: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o: in function `unixDlSym':
./sqlite3.c:42063: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o: in function `unixDlOpen':
./sqlite3.c:42022: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The project layout is:

- go.mod
- main.go
- sqlite3.c
- sqlite3.h

The contents if `main.go` is:

```
//go:build cgo
// +build cgo

package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
#cgo CFLAGS: -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1
#include "sqlite.h"
*/

import "C"

func main() {
}
```

I'm using Go 1.18.1.

Any help or nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think your preambles are correct (the comment lines before the `import "C"` statement). There can't be any whitespace between the `import "C"` and the preambles, and IIRC, you can't use the multi-line comment format

Comment: It worked! Many thanks!

What is interesting, though, is that in the mattn's go-sqlite package, the preamble is multi-lined.

Comment: Further experiments showed that there must not be empty lines between the preamble and `import "C"`, but the preamble itself can be multi-lined.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by saying there can't be any whitespace between your preambles and the `import "C"` statement. I'll post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed some C code inside a Go file, you write the C statements as something called *preambles*. There are certain strict rules regarding the formatting:

- `import "C"` is a standalone statement, and cannot be included in an `import ()` group
- The C includes and other code (preambles) immediately precede the `import "C"` statement, without any blank lines in between

So in your case, what you need is something like:

```
package main

// #include "sqlite.h"
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    // normal imports here
)
```

As you have since verified: preambles can be multi-line comments, so use whichever you prefer. The main thing is that there is no blank lines between them and the `import "C"` statement.